# Best way to include an xml url source in a Symfony project

Tags: php, xml, symfony, twig

I am a Beginner Coder and am wondering how to best include the following regularly updated xml file within a Symfony project (with Twig): https://www.la-spa.fr/adopter.xml?field_refuge_animal_target_id=97&field_esp_ce_value=2

I already manage to display the dogs name, picture but I also get "junk" information I do not want to display (like words "description", "sos : non"..., "refuge"...; and I just want ONE picture per dog)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFTjj.jpg)

Furthermore, I would like to add the dogs names within a dropdown menu in another file (Tattali's full calendar bundle BookingType.php file). The dogs displayed must be updated live according to the xml file.

Here is my current code (BookingType.php)

NB: I entered sample dogs name in the place where I want to display them from the xml file.

Thanks for your help.

```
class BookingType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('beginAt', DateTimeType::class, 
            [
                'date_widget' => 'single_text',
                'hours' => range(8, 20),
                'minutes' => [00, 15, 30, 45], 
                'label' => 'Début___________________',
            ])
            ->add('endAt', DateTimeType::class,
            [
                'date_widget' => 'single_text',
                'hours' => range(8, 20),
                'minutes' => [00, 15, 30, 45],
                'label' => 'Fin______________________',
            ]) 
            ->add('title', ChoiceType::class, 
            [
                'label' => 'Chien_______________________',
                'choices' => [
                    'Je choisis un chien' => '',
                    'Lucky' => 'Lucky',
                    'Lycos' => 'Lycos',
                    'Snoopy' => 'Snoopy',
                    'Lasko' => 'Lasko',
                    'Scooby' => 'Scooby',
                    'Rex' => 'Rex',
                ],
            ])
```

And ChiensController.php

> ```
>         /**
>  * @Route("/chiens/dog", name="dog")
>  */
> public function dog() 
> {
>     $curl = curl_init();
>     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.la-spa.fr/adopter.xml?field_refuge_animal_target_id=97&field_esp_ce_value=2');
>     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
>     $contenu = curl_exec($curl);
>     $xml = new simpleXMLElement($contenu);
>     
>     foreach($xml->channel->item as $v)
>     { 
>         echo ($v->title);
>         echo ($v->description);
>         
>     }
>     return $this->render('dog.html.twig');
>
> }
> ```

Comment: What do you mean by "include"? If there is stuff in that XML file that should not be used in your application, why not filter it out?

Comment: @NicoHaase, thanks for your reply.

By "include" I mean display through the files I mentioned on my post.

Filtering the information is precisely my problem.

As you can see in the xml file, the picture appears in the <description> (jpeg url) but I do not manage to just display the dog's name, the picture and, if possible, make the picture clickable to open each dog's full description page

Comment: How does your twig template looks like then?

Comment: @DarkBee, hi, well I have got a vertical display with all dogs and all pictures.

Here is a partial screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFTjj.jpg

The twig template I use is very very basic; like a base.html.twig. 

I did not specify anything in particular; except a CSS file I have not used yet

Comment: i mean like post the twig template :p

Comment: In fact the twig template is empty.

I just put extends base.html.twig but since I do not need it now the template is empty.

In fact I do not understand why you are asking me about the template: it is a code problem, right?